# Android: Custom style of RadioButton in AlertDialog

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I am building a RadioGroup in an AlertDialog like so:

```
val items = listOf("1", "2")

AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.MyStyle)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items.toTypedArray(), 0) { dialog, index ->
            dialog.dismiss().   
        }
        .show()
```

My desired outcome is to have this AlertDialog look like this:

[image]

So, with styling, I need to remove the actual RadioButton drawable, and then have the currently selected RadioButton have a grey background.

How do achieve this design using Android styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to accomplish that style using `AlertDialog.Builder`.

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_button_background_selector</item>
</style>
```

`radio_button_background_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/hig_light_grey" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

this data is showing in a List ? 
or its hard coded data ?

if it is listview or recyclerview its very easy to achieve  which you want.
in your adapter you just do this

```
 holder.cardlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                check=true; // this is local Boolean  type variable
                previousposition = position;  // previouspostion is local int type var 

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if (check) {
            if (previousposition == position) {

               //set color of card gray here

            } else {
               //set color of card is white here

            }
        }
```

keep in mind its aplicable if you use listview/recyclerview

Comment: I would like to keep the context given in my question the same – building the RadioGroup in an AlertDialog.